# How to Pass latitude and longitude from one activity to another

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to pass latitude from one activity to another, but I am a bit confused… I have written the code below.

On button click:

```
lat = Double.toString(latitude);
// lat = latitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Restaurant_List.class);
intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have declared `lat` as String. `latitude` is the variable double which already has the value. So I am passing String…

And on next page:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 19.666);
```

Of course I have added 19.66, that's why it will show that only. Otherwise if I don't put digits it shows error…

Or if I use `getStringExtra()`, it shows the by default page whose lat doesn't match with the lat I am passing. I searched a lot on the Internet but didn't get answer.

Comment: Simple pass latitude instead of lat.

Comment: Debug and show us here your value for getStringExtra("lat") please

Answer (score 1):

`lat` is a String value obtained after converting `latitude` which is the actual double value. So, pass `latitude` through the intent instead of `lat`.

```
intent.putExtra("lat",latitude);
```

Edit: Since the above method is not working for you, try putting your double inside of a bundle.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Restaurant_list.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putDouble("lat", latitude);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then inside your other activity, do this

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
double lat= b.getDouble("lat");
```

Comment: still it is taking the default value. :(

Comment: Did you remove the default value?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `LatLng` Object is Parcelable, you can pass it in a Bundle.

Add import in both Activities:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

First Activity:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Restaurant_List.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("location", new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
LatLng latLng = intent.getParcelableExtra("location");
double lat = latLng.latitude;
double lon = latLng.longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to String and pass

```
String latt=String.valueOf(lat);
Intent intent=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Restaurant_List.class);
intent.putExtra("lat",latt);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in Restaurant_List class, retrieve the String and convert:

```
Double lat=Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("lat");
```

Comment: try using sharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

```
    String message = String.format("New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude:%2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
    Intent intent=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Restaurant_List.class);
    intent.putExtra("lat",message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

its Very Simple to Send and Get The intent.

```
String lat = "10.12456521";
Intent intent=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Restaurant_List.class);
intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
startActivity(intent);
```

and In your Next Activity.

```
String lat;
Intent intent = getIntent();
lat =intent.getStringExtra("lat");
```

and After you casting into double.
Thanks